# Set selected option of type model in dropdownlist with knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

I'm trying to load the saved option from server side with knockout, please see below the general idea,

I have the following classes in javascript:

```
funcion Request() {  
    this.Id = ko.observable('');  
    this.Name = ko.observable('');  
    this.Form = ko.obsevable('');  
}

function Form() {
    this.Id = ko.observable('');
    this.Name = ko.observable(''); 
}
```

this is my viewModel

```
function RequestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Request = new Request();
    *self.Request.Form = new Form();*
}
```

I can save the Form without problem, but when I try to load the Form field saved into the database, the binding doesn't function.

If anybody have ever had the same problem, please let me know How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you loading the data from the server?

Comment: requestManager = new RequestManager(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

//into viewmodel
this.UpdateModel = function (serverData) {
self.Request.Form(new request(serverData.item.id,serverData.item.name));
}

Comment: That code won't work. Your `Request` class doesn't have a param in its constructor, so that data isn't loading the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You form is an observable. When setting an observable, you should call it as a method, and set parse the value as a parameter. Something like this:

```
function RequestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Request = new Request();
    self.Request.Form(new Form());
}
```

If you have loaded the form from the database, it should look something like this:

```
self.Request.Form(myLoadedForm);
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, the problem is that I am not loading only the form, I'm loading the complete Request viewmodel and the Form is a property into the Request, all properties are loaded but the only which is missing is Form maybe because is of type another model.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by aaberg is correct, but if you're saying you need to load them all at once, I recommend you use the knockout mapping plugin to automate this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Your call would look something like this:

```
ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(requestFromServer);
```